# Groovlet ServletContextListener failing to close SQL connection on destroy

Tags: sql, jdbc, servletcontextlistener, groovlet

I have a Groovlet (Groovy Servlet) which is working perfectly in every way, except when it's time to blow the context and deploy an update. When I delete the war file, the ServletContextListener.destroy is called on my implementation, which in turn attempts to close all open database connections. This appears to be getting stuck.

I'm typically using sql.firstRow for most of my queries in this application, and there doesn't appear to be any sort of way to close the underlaying PreparedStatement and ResultSet (other than the method closing). I'm not cache the results, but using BeanUtils.populate to copy the values in to a target bean for processing.

Could there be some other method I should call after each firstRow or eachRow before the final close?

I'm running Tomcat 6 under Java 6 and Groovy 2.1.1.